# Bash find all zip files within subfolders, bind files and their path into loop and perform some tasks

Tags: bash, loops, ls

I need to write script on Bash, which will find all zip files within subfolders, bind files and their path into some file, and then loop through this list and perform some tasks with all zip files (e.g. extract, check files within zip and then delete extracted files).

Some thoughts:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
echo $DIR   ##current dir
ls $DIR\*.zip
```

Then bind result to file (ziplist.txt for example)
Then read this file in loop per string:

```
if [[ some result ]] ; then
while IFS= read -r ; do

done <$DIR/ziplist.txt
```

How this can be done in best way? Sorry, I've have limited experience with bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
for filename in $(find . -name '*.zip'); do
    # Your operations here
done
```

If you want to keep using a while you can do:

```
while IFS= read -r ; do

done < <(find . -name '*.zip')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use find in many ways to do this.

"Your way" would be to create a temporary file and loop through this:

```
find /your/path -name '*.zip' > /tmp/zips
```

If you don't  necessarily need the collection of files but just want to perform a task to them as you find them, you can use find's exec:

```
find /your/path -name '*.zip' -exec /path/to/your/worker/script.sh {} \;
```

which will execute your script.sh for every zip file it finds, with the full zip file path as the argument.

Hope this helps.